# How to bring only price value which with text and curreny symbol?

Tags: javascript

Now I have NT$ symbol in price, so i want to remove it so i can bring the only price(number) into script to future calculate.
what should I change?

```js
var test = document.querySelector(".origprice");
var price = parseInt(fparent.textContent.replace(/NT/,/\U+00024/,/,/,''));
var testt = price - 150;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testt;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
<table id="table">

  <tr>
     <td class="origprice">NT$ 1,500</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<p id="demo"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to get the desired result.

```js
var txt="NT$ 1,500";
let t= ""
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g).map(i => {
 t += i ;
})


console.log(+t);
```

Comment: Hi! @ME-ON1 ! thanks for your help! it is work well but is there any way to make same result with "textContent.replace" form???

Answer (score 1):

If you will have space between prices and $, then you can do like the below,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let total = 0;
  $('.origprice').each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).text().split(' ')[1]);
  });
  console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="origprice">NS$ 10000</td>
  <td class="origprice">NS$ 20000</td>
  <td class="origprice">NS$ 30000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! @scsiva19911 ! thanks for your help! it is work well too but is there any way to make same result with "textContent.replace" form???